# Movie upside-down and left-right direction switching

Tags: vline

I am making application on vLine.

I wonder is it possible to change the direction of movie.

Currently,the pitcure on my camera(small frame) is left-right side reversed like a mirror.

It is sometimes a bit confusing.

If we can also switch upside-down ,
it is very useful especially using outside camera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTE: This answer assumes that you are not using the [uiVideoPanel widget](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.Options).

You can style the HTML element that is created as a result of calling  [`MediaStream.createMediaElement()`](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.MediaStream#createMediaElement) or [`MediaStream.createVideoElement()`](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.MediaStream#createVideoElement) with CSS. By default, the local video will be mirrored and the remote video will not. You can see an example of this by making a call with the [shell example](https://github.com/vline/shell-example).

You can apply a CSS [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) to the HTML element to mirror the image or flip it upside down.

To mirror, you'd use `transform: scaleX(-1)` and to flip upside down you'd use `transform: scaleY(-1)`. Also, you may need to add a [vendor-specific prefix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Browser_compatibility) to `transform`, such as `-webkit-transform`.

For example, in the [shell example](https://github.com/vline/shell-example) you can add the following in the `mediaSession:addRemoteStream` handler:

```js
  // flip remote video upside-down
  // 'stream' is the MediaStream
  // 'elem' is the result from stream.CreateMediaElement()
  if (stream.isRemote()) {
    elem.css('transform', 'scaleY(-1)');         // Firefox
    elem.css('-webkit-transform', 'scaleY(-1)'); // Chrome
  }
```

Comment: I am using the uiVideoPanel widget,,,you mean I cant use mirror upside-down with uiVideoPanel?

Comment: @whitebear Currently you can mirror the entire uiVideoPanel with CSS, but not the individual streams.